# Uploading jedis .jar file To Git Repository

Tags: java, git, netbeans, jar, redis

I'm following a [jedis tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_java.htm), and I can't seem to javac-compile java files with references to Jedis. I keep on getting this error:

```
error: package redis.clients.jedis does not exist
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
                          ^
```

I downloaded [this file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/redis/clients/jedis/2.9.0/jedis-2.9.0.jar) (named jedis-2.9.0.jar) from [this link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/redis/clients/jedis/2.9.0/) because it was the latest version at the time. When I right-clicked 'Libraries' in my Redis-based application and clicked 'Add JAR/Folder...', I successfully added the file and jedis runs normally in my Netbeans Environment.

[Picture of jedis jar in Netbeans Library Link because I need more points to embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntadk.png)

**The Problem**: I cannot compile any jedis java files in the command line. The error persists no matter what directory I'm in. I also want to save this .jar file somewhere within the repository so that when I commit this project to a git repo, the .jar comes along too.

Is there any way I can pack this .jar so it can travel with the rest of the files? I would love to put it in any of these locations:

```
> Projectname  
>> nbproject  
>> src  
>> test  
>> build.xml  
>> manifest.mf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not normally compiled a Java project directly with `javacc`.
You would use **[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)**.

That allows you to *declare* the dependencies (declare, as opposed to copy directly the dependency jar in your Git repo) in a **`pom.xml`** (small text file, well suited for a *source* control system like Git)

[In this instance](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.9.0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then (in command line) a simple `mvn install` would download the right file, add it to your classpath and build the project.

Comment: Thank you @VonC! Would I have to reconfigure my javaSE project to be a maven project? Or do I just need to make a pom.xml file and run mvn install?

Comment: Just add a pom.xml.

Comment: Can I make the pom.xml bare bones, like only doing <project>     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>    </project>

Comment: @beginner Yes: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM + a dependency section ought to be enough. Give your artifact (that you are building) in that pom.xml a dummy name and version.